# Telegram bot crash

Tags: mysql, python, sqlite3, telegram, telegram-bot

Hace un tiempo he estado desarrollando un game-bot de Telegram con Python y MySQL. Mi problema era que, llego a un punto, el bot simplemete dejaba de responder sin mostrar tan siquiera un error, pensé que tal vez era un problema de la Base de Datos y cambié a SQLite, pero el error persiste.

```py
import threading
import time
import funciones


class Manager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, tb):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tb = tb
        self.runing = True
        self.working = False

    def BrakingPoint(self):
        self.runing = False
        time.sleep(5)
        self.runing = True

    def isRuning(self):
        return self.runing

    def run(self):
        while self.runing and not self.working:
            secs = time.time()
            Combate = funciones.getCombates()
            if Combate is not None:
                self.working = True
                for i in range(len(Combate)):
                    if float(Combate[i][6]) <= time.time():
                        if Combate[i][7] == "No":
                            funciones.CombatRecompensas(Combate[i][3], Combate[i][1], Combate[i][2],
                                                        self.tb)
                        elif Combate[i][8] == "No":
                            funciones.CombatRecompensas(Combate[i][2], Combate[i][1], Combate[i][3],
                                                        self.tb)
                        else:
                            funciones.ExecuteInCombatAction(Combate[i][2],Combate[i][7],Combate[i][3],self.tb)
                            time.sleep(5)
                            funciones.ExecuteInCombatAction(Combate[i][3], Combate[i][8],Combate[i][2],self.tb)
                            funciones.RefresherTimers(Combate[i][0], time.time())

            Arena = funciones.getArena()
            if Arena is not None:
                if len(Arena) % 2 == 0:
                    for i in range(len(Arena)):
                        if ((i+1) % 2) != 0:
                            funciones.ArenaSetOponete(Arena[i][0], Arena[i+1][1], Arena[i][1],time.time())
                            enemyname = funciones.getHero(Arena[i+1][1])[1]
                            self.tb.send_message(Arena[i][1],
                                                 "Te has encontrado con `"+enemyname+"` en la Arena.",
                                                 reply_markup=funciones.MenuCombate())
                            enemyname = funciones.getHero(Arena[i][1])[1]
                            self.tb.send_message(Arena[i+1][1],
                                                 "Te has encontrado con `" + enemyname + "` en la Arena.",
                                                 reply_markup=funciones.MenuCombate())
                else:
                    for i in range(len(Arena) - 1):
                        if ((i+1) % 2) != 0:
                            funciones.ArenaSetOponete(Arena[i][0], Arena[i+1][1], Arena[i][1],time.time())
                            self.tb.send_message(Arena[i][1],
                                                 "Te has encontrado con `" + enemyname + "` en la Arena.",
                                                 reply_markup=funciones.MenuCombate())
                            enemyname = funciones.getHero(Arena[i][1])[1]
                            self.tb.send_message(Arena[i + 1][1],
                                                 "Te has encontrado con `" + enemyname + "` en la Arena.",
                                                 reply_markup=funciones.MenuCombate())
            print("Manager time execution> "+str(time.time()-secs))
            self.working = False
            self.BrakingPoint()
```

Este código no es más que el "Manager" de la Arena de combate, lo que hace es, cada cierto tiempo revisar si hay un número par de jugadores en la arena y los acomoda en un combate, también revisa las acciones ejecutadas por los jugadores que ya están en una lucha y las ejecuta de igual forma. Se pueden percatar que hay un método llamado BreakingPoint, lo implementé pensando que el error estaba en que la clase "Manager" al ser un bucle que por lo general no se detiene (algo similar al while(true)) terminaba provocando una especie de error de redundancia cíclica o ciclo infinito, pero resulta ser que el error no tiene que ver  con eso. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Vale, voy a editar mi pregunta y adjuntar mi código